# Blocks activated on Article content type

Tags: blocks

My website has heading blocks that appear for certain pages and (as expected) I have to specify that each heading block should only appear for /node/xxxx.

I have an Events content type, which are all articles. I would like to have a specific header block show up only for Events, if possible. I will have many, many events and would like to automate that process (if possible.)

I have not yet found a module that does this and searches only bring up programmatic solutions to putting articles inside blocks (which is the opposite of what I want.)

I'm wondering if there is a code that I could adapt/use to do this. If not, I am not sure whether I should be trying to do this in javascript, php or twig... so any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: Blocks already do this. Specify their visibility by content type, not by url paths.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I haven't had to use that feature for anything else yet and overlooked it.